# WSL file system permission mixed up with windows files

Tags: linux, wsl-2

I'm using WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for linux), and I've been using it for a really long time, and I didn't have troubles with it.

Unfortunately, today, from my linux distribution (Ubuntu 20.04), I no longer have permissions to view some Windows files, to which I had previously access without trouble. I don't know what happened, I don't remember intalling any update manually.

However, interestingly, I can access them if I do `sudo su` and become `root`. Then, I can access everything, or I can use `sudo cat`.  But I don't want anything of that, I want to be the default WSL user to do what I could before.

What I tried:

- Adding my default user to `admin` group, `root` group and `sudo` group (no luck)
- Addming username to `sudoers`

  ```
  root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
  danon   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
  ```
- Editing permissions in my Windows host machine to allow everyone to access it
- Editing permissions in my Windwos host to change the owner of the file (and directories below it)
- Use other WSL distros, Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 18.04
- Add `metadata` option to `/etc/wsl.conf`
- Restarting the distro
- Restarting the wsl
- Restarting the host system

I don't know what else to do. I don't want to do `sudo su` everytime I open my wsl, or call each method with `sudo`.

I would like either to access my files from WSL like I used to before, or maybe specifically make those files available to my default linux user.

Result of `mount`:

```
C:\ on /mnt/c type 9p (rw,noatime,dirsync,aname=drvfs;path=C:\;uid=1000;gid=1000;metadata;umask=22;fmask=11;symlinkroot=/mnt/,mmap,access=client,msize=65536,trans=fd,rfd=8,wfd=8)
D:\ on /mnt/d type 9p (rw,noatime,dirsync,aname=drvfs;path=D:\;uid=1000;gid=1000;metadata;umask=22;fmask=11;symlinkroot=/mnt/,mmap,access=client,msize=65536,trans=fd,rfd=8,wfd=8)
```

Comment: I think you should ask this question on https://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: I'd agree, or perhaps [Super User](https://superuser.com).  I find there to be a few more WSL users on Super User than on Ask Ubuntu, but either works.  I will say that your config looks good, so I don't have a clue why it's not working for you off the top of my head.